# Proving sets are countable

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Sort of new to this concept.

Trying to show that these 2 sets are countable or uncountable:

**{$n \in ℕ: n \leq 73$}**

and

**{$n \in ℤ: n \leq 73$}**

So I'm pretty sure that both sets are countably infinite but I'm not sure exactly how to show that in a simple way.

Comment: Are you certain the first one is infinite? How many non-negative integers do you know that are at most 73?

Comment: OH yeah right. That one is easy to prove then.

Answer (score 1):

To prove a set is countably infinite, one way is to find an injection from $\Bbb N$ to the set.  For the second, can you find an injection?  You should be able to find one that is a linear function.